# Hamzatu l-wasl, when case :if the final letter of the previous word has no vowel

Tags: arabic, arabic-translation

In book A New Arabic grammar of the written language, In case of Hamzatu l-wasl, when case :if the final letter of the previous word has no vowel, say  "it is given a vowel"
[image]

What does it mean "it is given a vowel"? For Example: In quran 23:14, for instant, at 23:14.6 "ٱلْعَلَقَةَ"
have Hamzatu l-wasl, at beginning, and previse word is "فَخَلَقْنَا", so how to pronounced "ٱلْعَلَقَةَ" as previse word's late letter(alif) does not have vowel. Here is [image]

Comment: Questions on Arabic language are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on their rule:

- If the last letter has no vowel and the letter is not itself a vowel sound like alif, waw, or ya, it is given vowel. E.g. زُلْزِلَتِ الْأَرْضُ

  Originally زُلْزِلَت ends in a sukoon, but it was given a harakah because it has hamzah al-wasl after it.
- If the last letter is an alif, waw, or ya acting like vowels, pronounce it as if the letter is not there.

Comment: In my given E.g:Quran 23:14.6, (above Main Q) 2nd point is valid i.e. " If the last letter is an alif, waw, or ya acting like vowels, pronounce it as if the letter is not there". I am right or wrong?

Comment: Yes. @PolarStar

Comment: Can you give more example on first point?